# GUI-designer in many cases not accessible in Monodevelop 7.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I haven't used Monodevelop for several months. Since I use the Xamarin-repository, the program has been recently updated from version 5.10 to 7.5. My problem now is that in many (all?) cases I can't find the toggle to switch between code and designer view if I load one of my old projects. If I create a new project that toggle exists but only during the same session. After a reload it disappears and I can't alter the GUI anymore. All I can do is to alter the automatically by the designer created files but this is really tedious and annoying. Any ideas? Anybody who encountered the same problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this kind of a workaround.

1. Open your file in the Sourcecode mode (even though you want to enter in Designer Mode).
2. Right-Click the tab with the filename, choose "close all files" from the context menu.
3. Double-click your file again in the project tree view.

Most of the time I get a chance to pick now from Sourcecode/Designer Tab

Answer (score 0):

Good for old projects, that there seems to be a workaround, although I haven't tried it yet myself. I generally have the impression that Monodevelop is not in good shape anymore. I think the best approach for GUI-programming targeting Linux / Mac / multi-platform is now using NET core, VS Code, the GtkSharp-Nuget-package and the glade designer. Make sure to save your GUI-files under the GtkBuilder-format.
This way you are even independant of C# and could, for instance, use F# instead:

```
    open Gtk    
    type MainGUI (filename: String) as this =
            let builder = new Gtk.Builder ()
            do
                Application.Init ()
                builder.AddFromFile (filename) |> ignore
                builder.Autoconnect (this)
            let quit (sender: Object) (args: EventArgs) = ()
```

This way you can also finally work with Gtk 3, which is much better.